# Finding a folder in a SharePoint document library by using C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have a list that stores the name of folders, I need to write a piece of code to find the folder in my document library and set the permission to contribute. if the folder does not exist in my document library, create a folder based on my the name in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2013/sites/team"))
{

    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {

        SPList docLib = web.Lists.TryGetList("DocumentLibrary");
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
        if (list != null&&docLib!=null)
        {
            foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
            {
                //check if the folder exists in document library.
                SPListItem folder = docLib.Folders.Cast<SPListItem>().Where(l => l.Title == item.Title).FirstOrDefault();
                if (folder != null)
                {
                    //set permission for this folder
                    SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups["MyGroup"];
                    SPRoleDefinition spRole = web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];

                    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spGroup);
                    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spRole);
                    folder.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                    folder.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);                                       
                    folder.Update();
                }
                else 
                {
                    //add new folder to the document library
                    SPListItem newFolder = docLib.Folders.Add(docLib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, item.Title);
                    newFolder.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```